# c# producto cartesiano de arrays

Tags: c#, array

Necesito hallar la forma de obtener todas las combinaciones que se puedan  dar cogiendo un elemento  del primer array y otro del segundo .
Pongo un ejemplo para que se entienda
ARRAY X=[A,B]   ARRAY Y=[1,2]

resultados que se buscan obtener o mostrar
A1
A2
B1
B2

en este caso tiene 2 elementos el array A y B pero podrian tener 5 y 8 elementos.
Como obtengo todas las posibles combinaciones,estoy programando en c# y necesito hallar una manera  de combinar varios arrays.

Comment: Mira quizá esto te sirva http://stackoverflow.com/a/1898744/6658955

Comment: Si es algo parecido pero ahi lo que hacen es hallar las combinaciones en de un solo conjunto de datos, yo deseo hacer la combinaciones pero cogiendo 1 elemento de un conjunto y otro elemento de otro conjunto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    static string [] combinar(string [] primerArray, string [] segundoArray)
    {
        string[] resultado = new string[primerArray.Length * segundoArray.Length];
        int c = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<primerArray.Length;i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < segundoArray.Length; j++)
            {
                resultado[c] = primerArray[i] + segundoArray[j];
                c++;
            }
        return resultado;
    }
```

Comment: Ya ló probé y funciona perfecto gracias! Tratare de hacerlo con tres arrays ahora,

Comment: En este caso, ¿los dos arreglos deben tener la misma longitud? creo que es importante agregar algo de descripción a tu respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Ya que se aceptó otra respuesta con una implementación tradicional, me permito agregar una respuesta para beneficio mas general.

Asumiendo que tienes las 2 listas siguientes:

```
char[] charList = { 'A', 'B', 'C' };
int[] intList = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

... estas son las 2 opciones que conozco para obtener un producto cartesiano usando una sola sentencia LINQ:

1. Usando [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) (<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/HFVC12730)</kbd>):

   ```
   var productoCartesiano = 
       charList.SelectMany(c => intList.Select(n => string.Concat(c, n)));
   ```
2. Usando [`Enumerabe.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), pero usándolo de forma equivalente a un SQL `CROSS JOIN` o `INNER JOIN ... ON 1=1` (<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/ASB30724)</kbd>):

   ```
   var productoCartesiano = 
       charList.Join(intList, c => 1, n => 1, (c, n) => string.Concat(c, n));
   ```

Comment: Sin duda una excelente respuesta

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @Flxtr :)